# How to fix this undefined symbol error while starting cups?

Tags: cups

I am installing cups. When I am starting cups by `/usr/sbin/cupsd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/cupsd: undefined symbol: _cupsMessageSave` error is being displayed. 
I am a beginner at cups and don't know much about it how to fix that.